# C++ 17 What is the difference between a fold expression and if constexpr when using variadic template arguments (parameter pack)

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, if-constexpr

I am trying to understand the difference between two approaches for handling parameter packs / variadic template arguments.

There are two approaches mentioned in the linked article below.

- fold expression
- `if constexpr` (I don't know if this has a formal name)

[Link to article](https://riptutorial.com/cplusplus/example/3208/iterating-over-a-parameter-pack)

Specifically I am interested to know how the compiler compiles these two approaches, and whether the output is a single function, or whether the output contains recursive function calls.

And more broadly, what are the advantages or disadvantages of using either method, if there are any to be aware of.

(I am thinking about this from the point of view of whether it might be possible to produce a stack overflow from too many nested function calls.)

My interpretation of what is written in the article is that the `if constexpr` method produces multiple single function calls once compiled, one for each function call which differs by the number of arguments.

However I may have misinterpreted this.

In other words, I interpreted this to mean that if the program contains two function calls to the variadic template function, and one of those function calls contains 3 parameters, and the other contains 5 parameters, then the compiler produces two separate functions, one with 3 arguments, and one with 5. But I may be wrong about this.

Can anyone clarify the situation?

Comment: The second form is actually called **`constexpr if`** because it is the `constexpr` form of `if`.

Comment: You need to include sufficient info in the question (without the link).  Maybe edit in sample code you wrote based off the article?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Since when has that been a rule

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant It's been a guideline since [at least 2009](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18669/should-posts-be-self-contained)

Comment: @NathanPierson first comment: "I think: It doesn't matter. People will still point to external sources when SO won't satisfy their needs." Regardless, this isn't really the place for a pointless discussion which isn't related to the question being asked.

Answer (score 1):

First, this:

```
template <class... Ts>
void print_all(std::ostream& os, Ts const&... args) {
    ((os << args), ...);
}
```

is a template that will generate only *one* function per call like so:

```
print_all(std::cout, "hello", ' ', "there", 5, "arguments");
```

Secondly, this:

```
template <class T, class... Ts>
void print_all(std::ostream& os, T const& first, Ts const&... rest) {
    os << first;

    if constexpr (sizeof...(rest) > 0) {        
        // this line will only be instantiated if there are further
        // arguments. if rest... is empty, there will be no call to
        // print_all(os). 
        print_all(os, rest...);
    }
}
```

is a template that will generate 5 functions for the same call. The cases are as follows:

- `print_all(std::cout, "hello", ' ', "there", 5, "arguments")`
- `print_all(std::cout, ' ', "there", 5, "arguments")`
- `print_all(std::cout, "there", 5, "arguments")`
- `print_all(std::cout, 5, "arguments")`
- `print_all(std::cout, "arguments")`

Comment: So actually, my interpretation was entirely the opposite of what happens

Comment: By the way, how did you find this information?

Comment: Well... by understanding how template instantiations work. If you want some concrete proof, you can look at the [generated assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/x5s7EcTGW) and see that it contains 5 different instantiations of `print_all()` :)

Comment: Yeah I can sort of see there are 5 things that look like they might be functions there. I'm not particuarly hot on assembly but it's good enough proof for me

Answer (score 1):

Fold expression is a easy way to operate a parameter pack:

```cpp
template<typename ...Args>
void print(const Args& ...args) {
    (std::cout << ... << args) << std::endl;
}
```

It's a syntactic suger that will unfold the `...`. (Without fold expression, you must use `template<typename F, typename ...Args>` and recurs to get every in the `...`)

---

`if constexpr` is `if` statement run in comile-time.

```cpp
template<typename T>
auto print_type_info(const T& t) {
    if constexpr (std::is_integral<T>::value) {
        return t + 1;
    } else {
        return t + 0.001;
    }
}

// Compiler will instancelize it like:

int print_type_info(const int& t) {
    return t + 1;
}

double print_type_info(const double& t) {
    return t + 0.001;
}
```

Conclusion:
They are just cleaner syntaces and have no explicit problem while using.

It's my understanding just. If there's any error, please tell me. :)